# Filter for 5 years or later

Tags: apex

I'm creating a filter for returned data. I'm using a IF statement. I need to make a filter where the returned policies does not show any policies that were terminated more than 5 years ago.

```
                if (YEAR((AgreEndDate__c)<=YEAR(TODAY())-5, true, false)){
                return;
            }
```

I keep getting errors focused on a List if anyone can help it wold be great.

Comment: Why not do that in SOQL as a filter?

Comment: I could, but the SOQL is very touchy. Hard to explain, but long story short is that I can't go threw the Query.

Comment: Can you add a bit more code? as of now it looks an uncompilable mix of Apex and Formula field.

Answer (score 1):

If AgreEndDate__c is a Date field:

```
Date.Today().Year() - AgreEndDate__c.Year() > 5
```

Review [Date Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm) documentation for more options.